# What statistical test to perform ? How do I compare the feature for two categories?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

I have a data set of 200 observations and 24 nominal features , 100 of those observations are for product A and remaining is for product B .
I want to check how differently those features attributes towards product A and product B .

My initial approach was to run a logistic regression and check the coefficients, but that doesn’t really make any sense since we will be checking for probabilities then .
Next I thought maybe check for Anova , but can I really check for example feature 1 of product A vs feature 1 of product B ?

What should be the right approach for this ?

Comment: Chi Squared is usually a good test for nominals. Have you looked into that, yet?

Comment: What's wrong with the probabilities?

Comment: Yes about the chi square test , that thought did come across my head . But is it okay to compare two variables of different populations? I mean we will be comparing feature of Product A and feature of product B .

Comment: The products have different features? Then what do you want to compare?

Comment: With regards to probabilities we will be checking how a feature would increase or decrease the chances of the product being A or B . So that why I think it would be irrelevant. If I am wrong please correct .

Comment: The probability of A vs B is *exactly* what a logistic regression models.

Comment: No . products have same features yes . Oh wait …. Now that I think about it . Yeah you are right , I was thinking it all wrong , yeah maybe I should try chi square test .

Comment: You say nominal features, how many values can they have? And, what is the goal of this exercise? Is it really only to test the null of no differences at all (in which case logistic regression might be a good solution), or it it more to describe the differences?

Comment: Yes , it’s just to check if the null and difference between two groups for a dependent variable . 
But correct me if I am wrong , a log regression would get me coefficients of those features and a probabilistic view of how a particular variable is affecting the probability of dependent variable. But my data has a dependent variable with two categories A and B and I want to check how groups of categories within independent variables(x) are different. So grps would be x1 which has only A and x2 would be only B . Now I want to compare x1 and x2.